# Does cats require boosting vaccine shot every year?

Tags: cats, vaccination

I will give my cat FVRCP vaccine.
I was told that it requires boosting dose after 3 weeks.
And that I need to repeat the vaccine every year.

Say for example I give the vaccine `@2021`
And a boosting shot 3 weeks after...

My question is : when she gets her vaccine `@2022`,
**do i give a boosting shot again after 3 weeks?**
Or that one time is enough?

And **does that also apply if I give that vaccine every 3 years?**

Also, **how long do I keep giving her the FVRCP vaccine?**
To a certain age or specific amount of times or forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vaccination recommendations will vary by country, product, age of pet, prior vaccination history, lifestyle, and other factors. It may also even vary by vet, as the guidelines have changed somewhat in recent years.

Your vet is best able to tell you what protocol is most suitable for your pet.

In general, my protocol for the FVRCP vaccine is:

- Kittens under 16 weeks: vaccinate at 8, 12, and 16 weeks.
- Cats over 16 weeks but incomplete or unknown kitten series: initial dose followed by booster in 3-4 weeks.
- Vaccinate at 1 year following initial series.
- Vaccinate every 3 years thereafter

If kept current, there should be no need to repeat the multiple vaccine booster series each year; a single booster dose will suffice.

In the recent guidelines from the American Association of Feline Practitioners, some vets have started recommending an FVRCP booster 6 months after the initial series, rather than 1 year, as it may confer better immunity for some kittens. Practically, I find this challenging for many cat owners to comply with as it will requires an extra vet visit. This type of protocol may be off-label for some products.

More detailed reading on the vaccination guidelines:

- [2020 AAHA/AAFP Feline Vaccination Guidelines](https://catvets.com/guidelines/practice-guidelines/aafp-aaha-feline-vaccination)
- [Small animal vaccination: a practical guide for vets in the UK (2017)](https://wsava.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Small-animal-vaccination-a-practical-guide-for-vets-in-the-UK-Michael-Day.pdf)

Comment: Worth mentioning that depending on individual risk, yearly vaccinations may be recommended by the vet. For example, prevalence of FeLV can vary considerably depending on country. Pulling numbers from memory, in North America two in one hundred cats your pet may encounter outside statistically carry the virus, while in Greece this can be as high as twelve in one hundred. Also worth noting that even an indoor cat might escape to the outside world at some point, so a vaccination regime not taking this into account has some additional risk in that regard.

Comment: Ok cool thanks a lot. How about `"for how long you keep vaccinating?"` ?

Comment: @RooTenshi every 3 years is for the rest of your cats life.

Comment: @trond , oh ok thanks for the answer. If you don't mind I'm curious to why is that the case. Shouldn't vaccines only be used to introduce the virus and strengthen the immune system for a period of time? Or there is a different story to cats? I know that's not my original question but I'm interested to learn more :)